# What does an exclamation mark mean in Java?

Tags: java

I'd like to confirm the meaning of `!=` before a boolean expression in a control statement means the opposite:

For example:

```
if (!networkConnected())
```

Does that mean "if the network is not connected"?

Comment: It does. `!` is interpreted as NOT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it does mean the logical opposite. It works even with ***equals*** operator.

Assuming your method return a basic bool type

```java
// means the Network is NOT connected
if (!NetworkConnected())
```

This is equivalent to

```
if (NetworkConnected() != true)
```

So logically means

```
if (NetworkConnected() == false)
```

Now assuming you method return a Boolean (indeed a real object), this means

```
// means the Network is NOT connected
if (! Boolean.TRUE.equals(NetworkConnected());
```

or

```
if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(NetworkConnected());
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer it explains it well. what if the value being returned is null ? Will the null be considered as a false value in this case ?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's boolean negation

So

```
true == true
!true == false
!!true == true
!!!true == false
```

Likewise with false

```
!false == true
```

The actual name for this unary operator is the `Logical Complement Operator` which inverts the value of a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The exclamation mark negates the boolean that appears next to it.

Answer (score 0):

To precisely answer your question: **no**. This operator `!=` is not negation. It means `NOT IDENTICAL` and is the opposite of `==` which stands for identity.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a unary operator that switches the boolean value of an expression.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
boolean b = true;

System.out.println(!b); // outputs: false
System.out.println(!!b); // outputs: true

b = !b; // first switch: b is false now
b = !b; // second switch: b is true now
```

So:

> Does that mean "if the network is not connected"?

Yes!

Answer (score -2):

In java,exclamation mark (`!`) that is used for inverted the value and also we call Boolean negation operator (`!=` being [not equal to](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)).

> example:if(string variable!=null)  here check whether string variable
>   is null or not.null means if block is not executed.otherwise it will
>   be executed.

Comment: `a != b` is equivalent to `!(a == b)`