# how to make If statement run with false boolean?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

i am still learning using code academy and they said that you can make a code run when the boolean value is false without using else by using an opposite boolean expression. Just curious, but how would you do that?

Comment: Negate the boolean expression. Lets say you have `boolean b = false` and want an `if` statement with `b` to run, then you would write `if (!b)`.

Comment: [`!` is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816444/java-basics-exclamation-mark)

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement cannot be performed if the condition is `false`. The one way here is using logical complement operator (`!`) that inverts the value of a `boolean` type.

For example,

```
boolean b = false;
if(!b) { ... }
// !b -> !false -> not false -> true
```

Also, you could surprise your teacher by knowledge of the ternary operator :)

```
System.out.print(!b ? "My homework is done!" : "I won't see it!");
```

Comment: `System.out.print(b ? "I won't see it!" : "My homework is done!");` is less obtuse.

Comment: @AndyTurner, it was needed to show the ! together with the ternary operator (it is obtuse, anyway)